# PHP - preg_match for (string),(string),

Tags: php, preg-match

This is my string:

```
(name1=value1),(name1=value1a,value1b,value1c),(name2=value2),...
```

I want the strings that are inside the parentheses. Means these:

```
name1=value1
name1=value1a,value1b,value1c
name2=value2
```

and etc...Note that inside the parentheses can be ANY character except ( and ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a purely RegEx answer, you can use lookahead/lookbehind assertions:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=\().*(?=\))/U", $text);
```

This means:

```
(?<=\()      A '(' character at the beginning
.*           Anything
(?=\))       A ')' character at the end
```

And the `U` at the end means that it's not "greedy". That means it won't just match everything within the first and last parenthesis.

Here's the code:

```
$text = "(name1=value1),(name1=value1a,value1b,value1c),(name2=value2)";
preg_match_all("/(?<=\().*(?=\))/U", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

And the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name1=value1
            [1] => name1=value1a,value1b,value1c
            [2] => name2=value2
        )

)
```

https://eval.in/46107

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other solution using `explode()`:

```
<?php

  $str="(name1=value1),(name1=value1a,value1b,value1c),(name2=value2)";
  $str = substr($str, 1, -1);
  $results=explode('),(', $str );

?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => name1=value1
    [1] => name1=value1a,value1b,value1c
    [2] => name2=value2
)
```